# jQuery AJAX success doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have this little AJAX call:

```
    $('#brick-mixer-form').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#mix-bricks-submit").addClass("load");
        $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Blander sten..");

        var form_data = $("#brick-mixer-form").serialize()

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "build.php",
           data: form_data,
           dataType: 'text',
           async: false,
           success: function(data) {
              $(".active").attr('src', 'build.php?'+form_data+'').load(function() {
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").removeClass("load");
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Bland igen");
              $("#bricks-selected").attr("value", form_data);
              $("#pdf_saver").css("display", "block");
           });
        }
     });
});
```

In Google Chrome this works perfect, but in Firefox I can only trigger it once.

When I press the submit button "`mix-bricks-submit`" again it will not run the call a second time.

Comment: remove `async: false`, Ajax starts with asynchronous not synchronous :)

Comment: Could you please add the HTML that goes with this JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the url parameter is not optional so either

```
$('#brick-mixer-form').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#mix-bricks-submit").addClass("load");
        $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Blander sten..");

        var form_data = $("#brick-mixer-form").serialize()

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "build.php",
           data: form_data,
           dataType: 'text',
           async: false, //I would avoid forcing synchronous
           success: function(data) {
              //$(".active").attr('src', 'build.php?'+form_data+'').load(function() {
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").removeClass("load");
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Bland igen");
              $("#bricks-selected").attr("value", form_data);
              $("#pdf_saver").css("display", "block");
           //});
           }
        });
});
```

or

```
$('#brick-mixer-form').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#mix-bricks-submit").addClass("load");
        $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Blander sten..");

        var form_data = $("#brick-mixer-form").serialize()

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "build.php",
           data: form_data,
           dataType: 'text',
           async: false,//I would avoid forcing synchronous
           success: function(data) {
              $(".active").load('build.php',form_data,function() {
                $("#mix-bricks-submit").removeClass("load");
                $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Bland igen");
                $("#bricks-selected").attr("value", form_data);
                $("#pdf_saver").css("display", "block");
              });
           }
        });
});
```

Although why would execute the ajax statement twice i am unsure of

Answer (score 1):

try this:

setting

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "build.php",
           data: form_data,
           dataType: 'text',
           async: false,
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) {
              $(".active").attr('src', 'build.php?'+form_data+'').load(function() {
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").removeClass("load");
              $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Bland igen");
              $("#bricks-selected").attr("value", form_data);
              $("#pdf_saver").css("display", "block");
           });
```

Comment: Hmm.. this still doesn't work. If I put an `alert("Test")` in the .load function it will trigger in FF, but the build.php is not reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This was added as an edit by the original asker, I have converted it to a community wiki answer because it should be an answer, not an edit.</sub>

SOLUTION:

```
    $('#brick-mixer-form').submit(function(e) { 

       e.preventDefault();
       var nowis = new Date();

       $("#mix-bricks-submit").addClass("load");
       $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Blander sten..");

       var form_data = $("#brick-mixer-form").serialize()

       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "build.php",
          data: form_data,
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(data) {

          $(".active").attr('src', 'build.php?'+form_data+'&tstamp='+ nowis.getMilliseconds() +'').load(function() {
          $("#mix-bricks-submit").removeClass("load");
          $("#mix-bricks-submit").attr("value", "Bland igen");
          $("#bricks-selected").attr("value", form_data);
          $("#pdf_saver").css("display", "block");
        });
     }
   });
});
```

By inserting a `tstamp` parameter into the query with a milliseconds value I will force a new image name every time the form is submitted which seems to override the cache issue in FF and IE.