# Alert not working in firefox but working in chromium

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

jquery:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  alert('This is working');
    $(".add_new").click(function() {
      $(".table").hide();
      $("#frm").show();
    });
      $(".insert_form").submit(function(){
    var sending_data = {
      "action": "insert"
    };
    sending_data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(sending_data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: sending_data,
      success: function(return_data) {
       alert(return_data); //This is not working.
     }
    });
  });
});
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['action'];
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="frm" style="display:none;" class="insert_form">
<input type="text" value="" required="required" placeholder="Enter your Name" name="user_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="clear" />
</form>
```

After submitting i have to display message. I am just testing using alert() but the alert box is appearing.Please Help.

Comment: POSTing a request will navigate away from the page.. so the alert will never be displayed if you put in in the success handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837364/jquery-ajax-success-doesnt-work-in-firefox This answer helped me. I have to add `async:false`

Comment: You should return false in submit or call e.preventDefault()

Comment: @shridhar That's usually not the way to go! Javascript is asynchronous.